# Using `getPrev` and `getNext` with entries sorted by SuperSort plugin?

Tags: templating, sorting, plugin-supersort

I applied the superSort plugin function to a list of entries and it works perfectly:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('sectionName').type('entryType').order('entryTitle')|supersort('natsort') %}
```

Trying to apply it to an entry page with this code to get the previous and next entry. It does not work:

```
{% set arrowParams = craft.entries.section('sectionName').type('entryType').order('entryTitle')|supersort ('natsort') %}
{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(arrowParams) %}{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(arrowParams) %}
  {% if prevEntry %}
    <a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">{{ prevEntry.title }}</a>
  {% endif %}

  {% if nextEntry %}
    <a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">{{ nextEntry.title }}</a>
  {% endif %}
```

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work with `getPrev` and `getNext`, as they only work with ElementCriteriaModels and not with an array of Entry models.

But that is what you get returned from the plugin. Supersort converts your `craft.entries` ElementCriteriaModel into an array of Entry models. This is necessary so that it can do the sorting.

The only workaround I know of would be to get the IDs of your supersorted entries and pass them to the ID param of a new ElementCriteriaModel.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('sectionName').type('entryType') %}
{% set entriesSorted = entries|supersort('natsortAs', '{title}') %}

{% set entryIds = [] %}
{% for entry in entriesSorted %}
    {% set entryIds = entryIds|merge([entry.id]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% set arrowCriteria = craft.entries.id(entryIds).fixedOrder(true) %}
```

Now you have an ElementCriteriaModel `arrowCriteria`, prepared to get entries in the desired sort order. So now you can use `arrowCriteria` with your entry methods.

```
{% set prevEntry = entry.getPrev(arrowCriteria) %}
{% set nextEntry = entry.getNext(arrowCriteria) %}

{% if prevEntry %}
    <a href="{{ prevEntry.url }}">{{ prevEntry.title }}</a>
{% endif %}

{% if nextEntry %}
    <a href="{{ nextEntry.url }}">{{ nextEntry.title }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

**On *natsort*...**

When you're sorting a list of entries, the items being sorted are EntryModel *objects*. The `natsort` filter won't be very helpful in that case, because `natsort` is expecting *string* inputs.

Instead you can use the `natsortAs` filter as described in the [Scraper docs](http://michaelrog.com/craft/lagniappe/supersort):

```
{% entries | supersort('natsortAs', '{someStringField}') %}
```

This way, SuperSort knows exactly which value to sort by, and your results will be consistent.

**On *getPrev()* and *getNext()*...**

The [`getPrev()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getPrev) and [`getNext()`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel#getNext) methods on an EntryModel relate to its order within a specific ElementCriteriaModel, based on the parameters you provided when you fetched the entries.

If you want to get the "previous" or "next" item in a sorted array, you can utilize Twig's [`loop` variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable).

`loop.first` and `loop.last` tell you whether you're at the beginning or end of the loop, and `loop.index0 + 1` and `loop.index0 - 1` will refer to the indexes of the next and previous items in the loop.

(c.f. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html)